# How to use last output of a for loop in r?

Tags: r, for-loop, output, linear-regression

I have a model matrix,
`X1=matrix(c(1,1,1,12,13,14,122,11,1,1,29,33),3,4,byrow=FALSE` 
Where each of the column represents one independent variable. i.e., `X1[,1]` is my first independent variable, `X1[,2]` is my second dependent variable and so on.
And dependent variable,
`y=c(12,11,4)`.
I want to run a linear model
`lm(y~ X1[,1] +X1[,2] +X1[,3]+X1[,4])` .
But, I have to this in the following way:

```
func_manual = function(X)
{
for(i in 1:4)
{
   if(i<2)
  {
        sum <- cat("(X1)[,") & cat(i,'\n') & cat("]+")
  }

   else
   {
    if(i>1 & i<4)
    {
        sum <-sum+ cat("(X1)[,")& cat(i,'\n')&cat("]+")
    }
    else
    {
       sum <-sum+ cat("(X1)[,") & cat(i,'\n') & cat("]")
    }
   }
}
sum
}
outut = func_manual(x)
Model=lm(y~outut)
```

The `outut` is giving my desired output:

```
outut = func_manual(x)
(X1)[,1
]+(X1)[,2
]+(X1)[,3
]+(X1)[,4
]
```

But I could not use the output of this function to run the `Model`.
Because, that is showing an error.  What is my mistake??

How to use this output?

Please clarify me how can I use the output of my function and run a linear model in this way.

I tried without using Function but that didn't bring me anything new.

Comment: *"I have to this in the following way"* ... Why? That seems not-optimal for many reasons.

Comment: As an example, your construction above regresses `y` on the four columns of `X1`. This can be also done using `lm(y ~ ., data = data.frame(y, X1))` without the need to construct a string and coerce into a formula.

Comment: Is your study to visit multiple ways of forming regression expressions in R? Or is it to explore different combinations of existing variables and those effects on `y`?

Comment: You can just run `lm(y ~ X1)` and if you need subsets of columns just select a subset of columns of X1, e.,g. `lm(y ~ X[,1:3])`

Comment: You are using `cat()` which prints to the console. Your function prints the formula to the console but nothing is returned to `outut`. Using `paste()` would return the character string and you could convert it to a formula using `as.formula()`, but there are better ways to build different regression formulas.

Comment: `cat` doesn't return a value (I mean, it returns `NULL`). And `&` and `+` to put the pieces together? Not in R... The way you are constructing `sum` is flawed since the beginning. Also, choose another name, there already is a function `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much simpler function. It uses `sprintf` to write the terms and `paste` to put them together. The summaries of the fits show equivalent fits.

```r
X1=matrix(c(1,1,1,12,13,14,122,11,1,1,29,33),3,4,byrow=FALSE)
y=c(12,11,4)

func_manual <- function(X) {
  n <- NCOL(X)
  regr <- sprintf("X1[,%d]", seq.int(n))
  paste(regr, collapse = " + ")
}


fit1 <- lm(y ~ X1)

outut <- func_manual(X1)
fmla <- paste("y ~", outut)
fit2 <- lm(as.formula(fmla))

summary(fit1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ X1)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#> ALL 3 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!
#> 
#> Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) 110.37624        NaN     NaN      NaN
#> X11                NA         NA      NA       NA
#> X12          -7.59406        NaN     NaN      NaN
#> X13          -0.05941        NaN     NaN      NaN
#> X14                NA         NA      NA       NA
#> 
#> Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:      1,  Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
#> F-statistic:   NaN on 2 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
summary(fit2)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = as.formula(fmla))
#> 
#> Residuals:
#> ALL 3 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!
#> 
#> Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) 110.37624        NaN     NaN      NaN
#> X1[, 1]            NA         NA      NA       NA
#> X1[, 2]      -7.59406        NaN     NaN      NaN
#> X1[, 3]      -0.05941        NaN     NaN      NaN
#> X1[, 4]            NA         NA      NA       NA
#> 
#> Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:      1,  Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
#> F-statistic:   NaN on 2 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @Tly Glad it helped. R's modelling functions work much better with data.frames, read the documentation for both `lm` and `reformulate`.